# Capacitor doesn't recive android specific push-notifications

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, capacitor

I try to implement push-notifications to my Ionic4-Capacitor-App.

In the app I have this code:

```js
PushNotifications.register();
PushNotifications.createChannel({ id: '1', description: '2019', importance: 2, name: '2019'});
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', (notification) => {
    console.debug(JSON.stringify(notification));
});
```

With POSTMAN I try to send the following message:

```
{
    "to": "<User-Token>",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Default Title",
        "body": "Default Body"
    },
    "android": {
        "notification": {
            "title": "Android Title",
            "body": "Android Title",
            "channel_id": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the documentation I used.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages)

The notification I recive has "Default Title" as a title and "Default Body" as a body.
I expected it to have "Android Title" and "Android Body". Additionally, the notification is not pushed to channel 1, but to Miscellaneous.

When I leave out the "root" notification part, no notification is displayed at all.

Comment: POSTMAN sends the notification to FCM and FCM to the device, so looks like FCM doesn't understand the android part and sends just the notification part. Do you have any link explaining the android part of the payload?

Comment: I am using this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages
I also added it to the question.

Comment: It says it overrides the notification title, so looks like a fcm bug to me. When in background or closed, the notification payload is not even handled by capacitor, but by the system, and it displays what it gets from fcm, so fcm is not overriding the title as it should

Comment: I did some more research and finally found a solution.
I used the old api, not the new one.... I had to do some more configuration to make it work. I wrote a step by step guide as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone who faces the same problem:
Here are the configuration steps I made to send firebase cloud messages via Postman.

Google-Cloud Configuration:

1. Go To: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent
2. Add getpostman.com to the authorized domains
3. Go To: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
4. Add a new OAuth-Client-ID
5. Select Webapplication and give it a name.
6. Set authorized redirect-URL to https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback and save.
7. Download Json for this account

POSTMAN Configuration:

1. Set Request-Type to POST
2. Enter the url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{your-firebase-project-name}/messages:send
3. Go to Authorization, select type OAuth 2.0 and click "Get New Access Token"
4. Grant-Type Authorization Code
5. Callback URL: https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
6. Auth URL: [auth_uri from the json File]
7. Access Token URL: [token_uri from the json File]
8. Client ID: [client_id from the json File]
9. Client Secret: [client_secret from the json File]
10. Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging
11. State: [empty]
12. Client Authentication: Send as Basic Auth header

When you have done these steps, you should be able to Send messages as described in this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send